# Unable to find the server's IP address even though an IP is defined

Tags: docker, jelastic

First of all, I need to warn you that I started to use Jelastic a few hours ago, so it might be a newbie question.

I'm using the "free trial" version of Jelastic, and made a few tests with them, where I tried a custom Docker image or a NodeJS environment.

I chose a MySQL image, a load balancer so that I have the SSL, and a NodeJS docker image.

It worked only once, the first time: I could reach the NodeJS image from outside, where a drawing game was available. After that, I only get the following error:

> This website is unavailable
>
> Unable to find the IP address of [the
>   auto-generated domain name thingy]
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

According to Jelastic, since I'm in free trial mode, I can't have more than one IP address, and it must be an IPV6. And according to this screenshot, it is enabled.

[image]

So... why can't I reach the server from anywhere?

**Edit: here are a few screenshots (sorry for the time it took)**

[image]

So after asking the question here yesterday, I changed the IP address from Nginx to NodeJS (just to test), and the error message got different, but not better:

[image]

It seems that somehow, even if I remove the ip from NodeJS to put it back to Nginx, I get the same error. No more DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, can't obviously tell why.

Here is how look my IP address on both nodes:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide more details on what is your goal? What topology you're going to get and what kind of access you're evaluating? Here is a link about Nodejs hosting @Jelastic https://jelastic.com/blog/nodejs-hosting-paas/

Comment: My goal is just to be able to reach the server from outside without trouble and without getting an "IP address missing" error. I recreated an environment several times while following the documentation, and still got the same error. I can provide you with more screenshots if necessary

Comment: yes, please. You can also contact us directly or with your hosting provider to speed up the investigation because now it looks like some custom case but not a common issue

Comment: @Jelastic I updated my response with a few screenshots, plus, I sent an email to Infomaniak's support this morning, I got no response so far (but it's not urgent so I don't mind)

Comment: @Jeanger, I saw your question. Maybe it is a bad redirection between the Nginx and the NodeJs server. I am based in Switzerland and I'm a Hidora customer. I recommend you if Infomaniak didn't already answer you, to contact Hidora's support. They are good guys and use as well Jelastic. Hope it can help you.

Comment: @Jaeger, have you found the root of the issue? Was it solved?

Comment: It seems that this problem was "unique", I recreated an environment, got the same error, created an other one again, and had no problem anymore. But I gave up on Jelastic, the price is too high for the use I'm gonna do with it (great plateform though)

Comment: @Jaeger, you can choose any hoster on [Cloud Union](https://jelastic.cloud/?pricing=0-0.005&sort=price_asc&regions=EU) sorted by price. Maybe there is one fitting your price expectation.